# fetch data from ms-access to ms-word

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word

i am looking to create an invoice in either MS-excel or MS-word. This invoice will contain several fields like invoice no., customer name, product info, quantity, Amount, Date, Address of customer, phone no. etc. The function of the invoice will be, to generate a unique invoice number, every time i open it, and then the vendor will mention the customer's info, product's info and click on submit button or save it. The info mentioned in the invoice will automatically be saved in the MS-Access database whenever submit button is clicked or the document is saved.

Thus, All the records of the customer will be saved in the MS-Access database. whenever i need to search for a particular customer, i should be able to search it from either invoice no. or any unique field for that particular invoice. I hope my query is explained clearly. please let me know the easiest way to do it. I do not have the vast knowledge about this subject, so give me suggestions that are understandable by a Novice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are starting from the wrong end. Use an Access form to get the data and then run a mailmerge, the easiest way is to output a text file from Access as the data file and use a Word template for the merge.

An autonumber may suit for invoice number as long as all you need is a unique number. If you need documented sequential numbers, you will have to create then yourself. How you do it will depend on the number of users working at the same time.

Comment: thnks for the suggestion. i was wondering if you can send me any example that can explain it better. i have already created the tables and form in Access. the only thing i need to do, is to fetch those details in the invoice.

Comment: @sumit Create a query for the invoice(s) to be printed, export it to text using `docmd.TransferText` (you could link to Access, but this is easier in the end), follow the Word wizards to create a mailmerge using existing data source, and select the file you have just created. Do this manually the first time and see if it all suits. If it does, it is just a matter of automating the running of the mailmerge. I can probably help you with code.

Comment: @Remou can't you define the word mailmerge to use an Access table or query as its source?  This would allow you to skip the `DoCmd.TransferText` step.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I mentioned that in my comment, however, it leads to another instance of Access being opened by Word; you can run into problems between versions; queries are far more messy to use in one version than another; finally, if you switch your data source you have to rework all the mailmerge templates. As a bonus, you get an historical record of the mailmerge with a text file. If you have tried both methods, I think you will go for the text output in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you now, generating Word files with Access is a bit of a pain in the ass. If you really want to do formatting it gets hard (is my experience).

I ended up generating HTML files in which I could control everything, and opening them as `.doc`s. But if you are really new to this, I suggest you start with some `VBA` tutorials, where they explain to you how you get records from you database and loop through them to generate output. And then you can start looking at file writing functions in `VBA`.

Can't find any tutorials real quick (my girlfriend is getting angry as we speak), but here is a sample:
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=25354

Just look around in fora, look for file generation and looping through records.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some links

Comment: i think there is a misunderstanding here. as explained earlier my first task is to insert the values of above mentioned fields and then save them in the database. later on, i want to search the customer from the database.

Comment: @saratis Running mailmerge from Access is not too bad at all.

Comment: Do you have any link or example that explain this

Answer (score 0):

Hi just reading your post, like Remou l would strongly suggest you use Access to enter and store the data.  It is possible to get a user to enter data into a spreadsheet and write the data back to Access DB. Not something l would recommend for the novice, [here is a link to some code on how it could be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113238/problem-updating-record-in-access-2007-database-from-excel-worksheet)

Returning to your first question, of creating the invoice have you considered generating the invoices from Access using a report?  They can be printed to PDF, or exported to various electronic formats.  Or is there specific reason to use Word/Excel?  If are going down the route of using Word to generate the invoice then use a template as Remou suggested.  See this [link](http://www.helenfeddema.com/CodeSamples.htm) for some samples see the section titled Access > Word.  I have used the examples as a basis for Access to Word.  A number of the examples though use a tecnology called DAO, which l understand will not be included in any operating system after Windows 7.  Just something to be aware of.

Searching for a record in a database table this [link has one possible solution](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html) .  Also the author has included a example database.